# Interaction and nested structure in symbolic formulae

Tags: mathematical-statistics, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I am using the following two structures, one simpler and one more complex, in `lme4` format which, as you can see, have an interaction term in the fixed effects as well as a nested structure with varying intercepts per dyad/participant and after that in the interaction per electrode.

`Signal ~ Repetition * Predictor + (1 | Dyad/Participant)`

My take on the 1st one is:
$$
Y_{i}=\beta _{0}+\beta _{1}Repetition\times Predictor+\varepsilon _{Dyad\mid Participant}+\varepsilon _{i }
$$

`Signal ~ Repetition * Predictor + (1 | Dyad/Participant) + (1 + Repetition * Predictor || Electrode)`

My take on the 2nd one:
$$
Y_{i}=\beta _{0}+\beta _{1}Repetition\times Predictor+\varepsilon _{Dyad\mid Participant}+\varepsilon _{Repetition\times Predictor\parallel Electrode}+\varepsilon _{i }
$$

I would appreciate some cross validation or correction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first model is specified as

`lmer(Signal ~ Repetition * Predictor + (1 | Dyad/Participant), ...)`

That means you have two random grouping factors in the model: Dyad and Participant. Also, Participant is nested in Dyad.

Each of these random grouping factors will need an index in your model: i for Dyad and j for Participant.

The way the model is formulated, it implies that the response variable Signal is measured repeatedly for each Participant within each Dyad.  Thus, you will need an index k to keep track of the repeated measurements of this variable.

With these indeces in place, your response variable Signal would become $Y_{ijk}$ in your model - the kth repeated value of Signal for Dyad i and Participant j.

The predictor Repetition will need to get its own indeces, depending on what level of your data hierarchy it is measured.

If Repetition is measured at the lowest level of the data hierarchy (i.e., each time you measure the response variable; observation-level predictor), you will have to denote it by $Response_{ijk}$.

If Repetition is measured once per participant within dyad (so it is a participant-level predictor), you will have to denote it by $Response_{ij}$.

If Repetition is measured once per dyad (so it is a dyad-level predictor), you will have to denote it by $Response_{i}$.

Same considerations apply for Predictor - you need to determine the appropriate indeces for it.

The notation (1|Dyad/Participant) implies that your model will contain an error term $\epsilon_{ijk}$ along with a random intercept for Dyad and a random intercept for Participant within Dyad.

The random intercept for Dyad can be denoted by $u_i$ in your model. The random intercept for Participant within Dyad can be denoted by $v_{ij}$.

Thus, the random error structure of your model will include the following:
$u_i + v_{ij} + \epsilon_{ijk}$.

Now you have a solid foundation upon which to build your model specification.

Comment: Still not very sure about the second model, the part where electrode comes, but I think I have a good foundation for the first one for sure. Thanks!